# Create document as Admin despite validation function

Tags: couchdb

How can an admin post documents to a CouchDB bypassing the validation function of a database?

It's stated in [CouchDB The definitive guide](http://guide.couchdb.org/editions/1/en/validation.html#writing) that this is possible, but it doesn't show how.

> Admins can create and delete design documents despite the existence of this extreme validation function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The guide is refering to **design** documents not to normal content documents. So Admins are retricted by the same validation functions that the rest of users.

The exception for allow admin edits should be coded in the validation function.

Comment: Oh, I get it. So, basically, admins _can sort of_  create new documents: delete the validate_function design document, create docs, restore the previous validate_function.

Comment: Or you can add an exception for admins in the validate_function